Toggle animation to show/hide Div by slidding style
I want to paly second div animation within its parent row only. Right now the second div is moving out of the row boundary. How can I handle this? This is my first time trying first time animation. Thanks in advance.


function test(event) {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('toggle');
  var firstDiv = document.getElementById('firstDiv');
  var secondDiv = document.getElementById('secondDiv');

  if (checkbox.checked) {
    secondDiv.classList.remove('col-lg-12')
    secondDiv.classList.remove('slide-in');
    secondDiv.classList.add('col-lg-7')
    secondDiv.classList.add('slide-out');
    //firstDiv.style.display = 'block';
    secondDiv.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
      firstDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }, {
      once: true
    });
  } else {
    firstDiv.style.display = 'none';
    secondDiv.classList.remove('slide-out');
    secondDiv.classList.remove('col-lg-7')
    secondDiv.classList.add('col-lg-12')
    secondDiv.classList.add('slide-in');
  }
}
.slide-in {
  animation: slide-in 3s forwards;
}

.slide-out {
  animation: slide-out 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* Added row border */
  width: 500px;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div id="firstDiv" style="background-color:palegreen" class="col-lg-5">first</div>
  <div id="secondDiv" style="background-color:yellow" class="col-lg-7">Second</div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked="checked" onchange="test(event)">
  <label for="toggle">Toggle Animation</label>
</div>




So you want to set overflow: hidden on the parent .row element then ...?

No overflow : hidden will not work

Then please give a better explanation of how you actually want this to behave, because I currently can't tell what exactly you want instead.

Please describe what ‘within its parent row’ means.

This is what I initially thought you wanted - despite you saying that "overflow: hidden won't work" above - so, please take a look (https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gjyexz5w/), and explain clearly what's wrong with the demo. What does it do wrong? What doesn't it do that you need it to do?

Parent row means , Parent Div, which have the classs named like row

Okay so when toggle Animation is on (checked box checked) then we need to show first and second both the div

I think you're going to have to show some pictures to explain the end-states, the start and finish of the animation.

I have tried to resolve your issue.
You're moving the div by 100% using animation.
.slide-in {
  animation: slide-in 3s forwards;
}

.slide-out {
  animation: slide-out 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* Added row border */
  width: 500px;
}

OR you can change the direction.
.slide-in {
  animation: slide-in 3s forwards;
}

.slide-out {
  animation: slide-out 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* Added row border */
  width: 500px;
}


Not working , as well as  transform: translateY(-100%); will add the sliding from top to bottom which is wrong . I just need to left to right and right to left animation only

Please try this.
@keyframes slide-out {
from {
transform: translateX(-100%);
}
to {
transform: translateX(0);
}
}

keyframes slide-out {
from {
transform: translateX(100%);
}
to {
transform: translateX(0);
}
}
This will slide out from right to left and fit in properly.
OR this one.
This will start from invisible and end up the way you want.
keyframes slide-out {
from {
transform: translateX(-100%);
}
to {
transform: translateX(0);
}
}

Solution is pretty simple but let me explain what is cause of issue first. The div is currently overflowing out of its parent div due to which you can see div moving out of parent div border. To fix this issue you just need to add overflow: hidden to row and it will be fixed.
Below is working example and if I have missed something then do share.


function test(event) {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('toggle');
  var firstDiv = document.getElementById('firstDiv');
  var secondDiv = document.getElementById('secondDiv');

  if (checkbox.checked) {
    secondDiv.classList.remove('col-lg-12')
    secondDiv.classList.remove('slide-in');
    secondDiv.classList.add('col-lg-7')
    secondDiv.classList.add('slide-out');
    //firstDiv.style.display = 'block';
    secondDiv.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
      firstDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }, {
      once: true
    });
  } else {
    firstDiv.style.display = 'none';
    secondDiv.classList.remove('slide-out');
    secondDiv.classList.remove('col-lg-7')
    secondDiv.classList.add('col-lg-12')
    secondDiv.classList.add('slide-in');
  }
}
.slide-in {
  animation: slide-in 3s forwards;
}

.slide-out {
  animation: slide-out 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* Added row border */
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div id="firstDiv" style="background-color:palegreen" class="col-lg-5">first</div>
  <div id="secondDiv" style="background-color:yellow" class="col-lg-7">Second</div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked="checked" onchange="test(event)">
  <label for="toggle">Toggle Animation</label>
</div>




after the toggle Animation on second div is not visible in your case if overflow is hidden

@user547534 Can't understand what you are trying to explain.
